# List out the audio files the way they are in the directory

Tags: python

I have a directory that contain audio files and I want my code to list out the files the way they are in the directory. However, the code is not listing them out the way they are in the directory instead it sorted them out and missed everything up. I set the reverse to true and passed it into the sort method but it still did not work and I also set it to true but it did not work either. the output files are all missed up.

This is part of what I have in DCB folder:

```
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_216285_231548.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_293006_305864.mp3
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_326142_335937.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_360798_369361.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_407710_413108.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_434235_440906.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_457131_472934.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_493519_499002.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_524265_532609.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_538399_544113.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_548467_558696.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_563943_573153.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_596358_614352.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_616454_626181.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_665292_672333.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_674039_691608.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_713213_722366.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_739387_747606.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_785381_804253.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_805477_829554.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_908650_918901.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_934284_939624.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_940041_965741.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_974583_980062.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_980894_999268.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1002411_1038909.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1058180_1106086.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1137188_1154185.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1191138_1197065.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1201294_1216302.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1256071_1262822.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1296890_1315589.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1433172_1439219.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1451640_1459994.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1460711_1466174.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1525936_1532454.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1580609_1592344.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1597704_1603279.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1604468_1609915.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1634815_1655246.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1672373_1679173.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1703458_1712057.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1716310_1734363.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1761395_1784671.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1861353_1896123.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1919798_1937698.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1965098_1982911.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1983992_1996235.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2022190_2065446.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2076888_2086149.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2108556_2114873.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2132160_2138066.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2139946_2146323.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2147274_2164025.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2179931_2186579.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2193689_2211074.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2212715_2228052.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2236692_2262221.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2294262_2316482.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2341544_2347903.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2391241_2397036.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2506577_2516148.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2532139_2538502.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2545430_2553044.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2572284_2610782.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2642204_2650437.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2651873_2688386.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2727608_2746149.mp3,
```

In the folder, the audio files started with:

```
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_216285_231548.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_293006_305864.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_326142_335937.mp3
```

Below is my code:

```
coraal_mp3 = 'data/DCB/'
files = []

for filename in os.listdir(coraal_mp3):
    if filename.endswith(".mp3") and filename != "audio.mp3":
        files.append(filename)
#print("completed")
#files.sort(reverse=True)
files.sort()
```

Here is the output:

```
['DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1002411_1038909.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1002411_1038909.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1002411_1038909.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1002411_1038909.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1002411_1038909.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1058180_1106086.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1058180_1106086.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1058180_1106086.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1058180_1106086.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1058180_1106086.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1137188_1154185.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1137188_1154185.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1137188_1154185.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1137188_1154185.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1137188_1154185.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1191138_1197065.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1191138_1197065.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1191138_1197065.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1191138_1197065.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1191138_1197065.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1201294_1216302.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1201294_1216302.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1201294_1216302.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1201294_1216302.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1201294_1216302.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1256071_1262822.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1256071_1262822.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1256071_1262822.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1256071_1262822.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1256071_1262822.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1296890_1315589.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1296890_1315589.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1296890_1315589.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1296890_1315589.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1296890_1315589.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1433172_1439219.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1433172_1439219.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1433172_1439219.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1433172_1439219.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1433172_1439219.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1451640_1459994.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1451640_1459994.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1451640_1459994.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1451640_1459994.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1451640_1459994.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1460711_1466174.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1460711_1466174.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1460711_1466174.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1460711_1466174.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1460711_1466174.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1525936_1532454.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1525936_1532454.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1525936_1532454.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1525936_1532454.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1525936_1532454.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1580609_1592344.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1580609_1592344.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1580609_1592344.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1580609_1592344.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1580609_1592344.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1597704_1603279.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1597704_1603279.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1597704_1603279.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1597704_1603279.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1597704_1603279.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1604468_1609915.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1604468_1609915.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1604468_1609915.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1604468_1609915.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1604468_1609915.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1634815_1655246.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1634815_1655246.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1634815_1655246.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1634815_1655246.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1634815_1655246.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1672373_1679173.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1672373_1679173.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1672373_1679173.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1672373_1679173.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1672373_1679173.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1703458_1712057.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1703458_1712057.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1703458_1712057.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1703458_1712057.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1703458_1712057.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1716310_1734363.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1716310_1734363.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1716310_1734363.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1716310_1734363.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1716310_1734363.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1761395_1784671.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1761395_1784671.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1761395_1784671.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1761395_1784671.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1761395_1784671.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1861353_1896123.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1861353_1896123.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1861353_1896123.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1861353_1896123.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1861353_1896123.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1919798_1937698.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1919798_1937698.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1919798_1937698.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1919798_1937698.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1919798_1937698.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1965098_1982911.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1965098_1982911.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1965098_1982911.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1965098_1982911.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1965098_1982911.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1983992_1996235.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1983992_1996235.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1983992_1996235.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1983992_1996235.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1983992_1996235.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2022190_2065446.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2022190_2065446.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2022190_2065446.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2022190_2065446.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2022190_2065446.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2076888_2086149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2076888_2086149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2076888_2086149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2076888_2086149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2076888_2086149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2108556_2114873.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2108556_2114873.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2108556_2114873.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2108556_2114873.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2108556_2114873.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2132160_2138066.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2132160_2138066.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2132160_2138066.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2132160_2138066.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2132160_2138066.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2139946_2146323.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2139946_2146323.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2139946_2146323.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2139946_2146323.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2139946_2146323.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2147274_2164025.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2147274_2164025.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2147274_2164025.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2147274_2164025.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2147274_2164025.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_216285_231548.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_216285_231548.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_216285_231548.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_216285_231548.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_216285_231548.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2179931_2186579.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2179931_2186579.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2179931_2186579.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2179931_2186579.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2179931_2186579.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2193689_2211074.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2193689_2211074.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2193689_2211074.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2193689_2211074.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2193689_2211074.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2212715_2228052.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2212715_2228052.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2212715_2228052.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2212715_2228052.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2212715_2228052.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2236692_2262221.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2236692_2262221.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2236692_2262221.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2236692_2262221.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2236692_2262221.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2294262_2316482.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2294262_2316482.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2294262_2316482.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2294262_2316482.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2294262_2316482.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2341544_2347903.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2341544_2347903.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2341544_2347903.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2341544_2347903.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2341544_2347903.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2391241_2397036.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2391241_2397036.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2391241_2397036.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2391241_2397036.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2391241_2397036.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2506577_2516148.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2506577_2516148.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2506577_2516148.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2506577_2516148.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2506577_2516148.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2532139_2538502.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2532139_2538502.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2532139_2538502.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2532139_2538502.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2532139_2538502.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2545430_2553044.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2545430_2553044.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2545430_2553044.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2545430_2553044.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2545430_2553044.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2572284_2610782.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2572284_2610782.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2572284_2610782.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2572284_2610782.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2572284_2610782.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2642204_2650437.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2642204_2650437.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2642204_2650437.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2642204_2650437.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2642204_2650437.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2651873_2688386.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2651873_2688386.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2651873_2688386.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2651873_2688386.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2651873_2688386.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2727608_2746149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2727608_2746149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2727608_2746149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2727608_2746149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2727608_2746149.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2747234_2757244.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2747234_2757244.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2747234_2757244.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2747234_2757244.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_2747234_2757244.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_293006_305864.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_293006_305864.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_293006_305864.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_293006_305864.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_293006_305864.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_326142_335937.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_326142_335937.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_326142_335937.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_326142_335937.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_326142_335937.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_360798_369361.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_360798_369361.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_360798_369361.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_360798_369361.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_360798_369361.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_407710_413108.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_407710_413108.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_407710_413108.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_407710_413108.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_407710_413108.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_434235_440906.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_434235_440906.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_434235_440906.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_434235_440906.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_434235_440906.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_457131_472934.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_457131_472934.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_457131_472934.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_457131_472934.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_457131_472934.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_493519_499002.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_493519_499002.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_493519_499002.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_493519_499002.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_493519_499002.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_524265_532609.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_524265_532609.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_524265_532609.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_524265_532609.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_524265_532609.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_538399_544113.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_538399_544113.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_538399_544113.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_538399_544113.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_538399_544113.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_548467_558696.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_548467_558696.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_548467_558696.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_548467_558696.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_548467_558696.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_563943_573153.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_563943_573153.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_563943_573153.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_563943_573153.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_563943_573153.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_596358_614352.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_596358_614352.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_596358_614352.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_596358_614352.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_596358_614352.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_616454_626181.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_616454_626181.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_616454_626181.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_616454_626181.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_616454_626181.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_665292_672333.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_665292_672333.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_665292_672333.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_665292_672333.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_665292_672333.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_674039_691608.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_674039_691608.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_674039_691608.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_674039_691608.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_674039_691608.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_713213_722366.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_713213_722366.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_713213_722366.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_713213_722366.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_713213_722366.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_739387_747606.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_739387_747606.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_739387_747606.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_739387_747606.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_739387_747606.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_785381_804253.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_785381_804253.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_785381_804253.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_785381_804253.mp3',
 'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_785381_804253.mp3',
```

The output did not start with these:

```
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_216285_231548.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_293006_305864.mp3,
DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_326142_335937.mp3
```

I want the output of my code to be able to match with what I have in the DCB folder

Comment: In your last statement from code you are sorting so may be it can be reason

Comment: From what I gather, the issue is that these files have an ordering based on information internal to their names and that a text sort causes the ordering to mess up as what you really want is some parts of the name to be sorted numerically. You will want to write a key function for your sort that breaks the name up into parts and sorts based on casting some of the parts to `int()`

Comment: @BhavyaParikh, I do not think that is the reason because I commented that line and ran the program again but I got the same output

Answer (score 0):

Some components of the filename seem to have numeric significance rather than just a simple text significance. So, a text sorting alone is not going to work. You will need to sort by breaking the filenames into pieces and then casting some of them to `int()` to get the sorting I think you want.

This might get you unstuck. It is simple and brittle though so you will likely want to improve on it.

```
import json # just for pretty printing

# enough data to show what is happening
data = [
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3',
    'DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3'
]

# now let's sort based on the first "longer" integer in the name
data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split("_")[6]))

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

This results in:

```
[
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_179711_185563.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1786258_1795160.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3",
    "DCB_se1_ag2_f_01_1_1838210_1860533.mp3"
]
```